# how to add a gesture recogniser to a uiview in a collectionview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uicollectionviewcell

I have a full screen horizontal collectionview.

1. scrolling is disabled
2. paging is enabled, there are next/prev buttons for the paging.

In my collectionview cell i have a label that i want to recognise when the user swipes it to the left/right.
After i added the gesture to the label nothing happens.

CODE:

collectionViewCell:

```
func addGesture(){
    let right = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: myLabel, action: "test")
    right.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
    answer.addGestureRecognizer(right)
}
```

view controller:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("formQuestionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as QuestionCell

    cell.addGesture()

    return cell
}
```

I also tries to switch the target from myLabel to self and it still doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would move the `addGesture` code to the view controller so that you can handle the swipes in the view controller as well.

Change

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

to

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("formQuestionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as QuestionCell

    let right = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("test:"))
    right.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
    cell.answer.addGestureRecognizer(right) // I am assuming 'answer' is an outlet to the label you want to add a gesture recognizer to in the QuestionCell class

    return cell
}
```

and then you need to implement `test:` in the view controller as well (because you set the target to `self`):

```
func test(gestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    // Deal with swipe
}
```

Comment: Thanks,
i get a unrecognised selector sent to instance.

Comment: Did you implement `test:` in the view controller as well? You need to otherwise you'll get errors like that. Whatever you set the `target` has to implement that selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                         initWithTarget:self action:@selector(clickEventOnImage:)];

[tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[tapRecognizer setDelegate: self];
cell.uiviewelement.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[cell.uivielement addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```